# Oauth yahoo create folder

Tags: oauth, yahoo

I'm trying to [Create Folder](http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/docs/user_guide/CreateFolder.html#) in yahoo mailer and move some messages to it ..
it was working properly but suddenly a weird response message is received

```
{"result":null,"error":{"code":"Client.RestrictedOAuthApiCall","message":"Account scopes <answ-w,mail-x,sdct-r,sdps-r,sdst-w,sdup-r,wrch-r> not allowed to call <CreateFolder>","detail":null}}
```

can anyone tell me why this response is received ?

Comment: thanks sir, the problem was just because there is someone who change my privileges in yahoo's account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was just because there is someone who change my privileges in yahoo's account.